# Python: efficient operations on numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a numpy array x:

```
x = array([[  3,   2,   1],
           [  3,  25,  34],
           [ 33, 333,   3],
           [ 43,  32,   2]])
```

I want to carry out the following operations *without explicitly writing a for loop* i.e. say a method which uses automatic in built looping;

1) Replace the 2nd column by a column of all 1 i.e.

```
x = array([[  3,   1,   1],
           [  3,   1,  34],
           [ 33,   1,   3],
           [ 43,   1,   2]])
```

2) In the original array , replace 3rd column with the product of 2nd and 3rd i.e.

```
x = array([[  3,   2,   1*2],
           [  3,  25,  34*25],
           [ 33, 333,   3*333],
           [ 43,  32,   2*32]])
```

3) Finally, I would like to replace the 2nd column in the original array based on a condition i.e.

```
x[1] = 0  if x[0] > 5 else 4
```

i.e. the array now looks like:

```
x = array([[  3,   4,   1],
           [  3,   4,  34],
           [ 33,   0,   3],
           [ 43,   0,   2]])
```

Any suggestions ?
Thanks !

Comment: You can do this using a `while` loop and an iterator variable that is incremented with every loop. May I ask why you can't use a `for` loop?

Comment: The array might get very tall, i.e say million elements, which might be repeated 100's of times. Using an explicit `for` loop is adding a lot of overhead. Therefore, I switched to `numpy array` in place of `lists`, hopping that there will be some kind of `vectorized` solution to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation on numpy is well worth reading as this is fairly basic stuff...

1. `x[:,1]` = 1
2. `x[:,2] *= x[:,1]`
3. `x[:,1] = np.where( x[:,0] > 5, 0, 4 )`

Comment: Jon Clements: Thanks for this ! I was indexing in the wrong way, something like x[:][1] .. Thanks again for this !

Comment: Number 2 can be improved by using `x[:,2] *= x[:,1]` – this saves the creation of a temporary array.

Comment: @Sven good point - not sure why I didn't write that - thanks - edited